# How to get the genomic sequences from a blat result?

Tags: python, bedtools, data-preprocessing, blat

Assume we have a `query.fa` file that contains sequences and we run:

`blat -stepSize=5 -repMatch=2253 -minScore=20 -minIdentity=0 -out=pslx /genomes/mm10.fa.qz query.fa output.pslx`

the output `output.pslx` file looks like this:

```
match   mis-    rep.    N's     Q gap   Q gap   T gap   T gap   strand  Q               Q       Q       Q       T               T       T       T       block       blockSizes      qStarts  tStarts
        match   match           count   bases   count   bases           name            size    start   end     name            size    start   end     count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       +       seq     20      0       20      chr9    124595110       44046930        44046950   20,      0,      44046930,       aaaagtatcagtgtgtatag,   aaaagtatcagtgtgtatag,
20      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       +       seq     20      0       20      chr9    124595110       44046930        44046950   20,      0,      44046930,       aaaagtatcagtgtgtatag,   aaaagtatcagtgtgtatag,
```

What would be a reasonable way to get the genomic contexts (5bp upsteam and 5bp downstream) for each aligned sequence.

For example, assume that `blat` found that the seq: `AAATTGGGGAAAA` aligns to `chr2:100-113`, so the question is how to get `chr2:95-118` easily without reinventing the wheel.

---

I couldn't make it work with bedtools, because my genome's index file is corrupted, but this should work for others who have successfully used `bwa` or `samtools` to index their reference genome:

```
blat -stepSize=5 -repMatch=2253 -minScore=20 -minIdentity=0 -out=pslx /genomes/mm10.fa.qz query.fa output.pslx
awk 'NR>5 {print $14 "\t" $16-10"\t" $17+10}' output.pslx > regions.bed
bedtools getfasta -fi /genomes/mm10.fa.gz -bed regions.bed
```

Comment: https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SearchIO.BlatIO-module.html

Comment: Creat a bed file with `chr2 95 118` inside, and then use it with `bedtools getfasta` to extract your region

Comment: @user3479780 I tried that. Add some issue with indexing my reference genome. But this should work too. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Via BEDOPS `convert2bed` (`psl2bed`) and `bedops` operations:

```
$ psl2bed < hits.psl | bedops --range 5 --everything - > answer.bed
```

The file `answer.bed` will contain target intervals from the PSL (BLAT) input, padded up- and downstream by five bases.

This BED file can be run through `samtools faidx` or [similar](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/5374/776) to get sequence data.

References:

- https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/file-management/conversion/psl2bed.html
- https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/set-operations/bedops.html#range-range

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with varied: `pcl2bed`, `samtools`, `bedtools` commands. I think this biopython should work:

```
import gzip
from Bio import SeqIO
n=5

exact_matches = {}
blat_qresult = SearchIO.read('blat_output.pslx', 'blat-psl', pslx=True)
for hit in blat_qresult:
    for f in hit.fragments:
        if f.hit_span == f.query_span:
            chrom = hit.id
            if chrom not in exact_matches:
                exact_matches[chrom] = []
            exact_matches[chrom].append(f.hit_range)


with gzip.open('/genomes/mm10.fa.gz', "rt") as handle:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
        if record.id in exact_matches:
            for subseq in exact_matches[record.id]:
                print(record.seq[subseq[0]-n:subseq[1]+n])
```